# Sqlite Joining 2 tables via Union by Groups

Tags: sqlite

I have a data table "datatable" that is updated daily.

```
DATATABLE
Shop    Manager    Sales    Date
1       A          100      20181217
1       B          120      20181217
2       C          110      20181217
2       D          105      20181217
1       A          100      20181218
```

Data is periodically cleaned and put in "cleantable" with the same columns.  I am trying to create a view table that merges these 2 tables and give me cleaned data when available, uncleaned otherwise.

```
CLEANTABLE
Shop    Manager    Sales    Date
1       A          101      20181217
1       B          121      20181217
```

I can do this with union for 1 shop & 1 manager.

```
select * from cleantable where Shop = 1 and Manager = 'A' 
union
select * from datatable where Shop = 1 and Manager = 'A' where Date > 
(select max(Date) from cleantable where Shop = 1 and Manager = 'A')
```

The cleaning dates for each shop and manager is different.

Is there an easy way to write a query that takes care of all shop/manager combinations.

Ideally it should also work if a particular shop/manager combination has no clean data.

```
DESIRED OUTPUT
Shop    Manager    Sales    Date
1       A          101      20181217
1       B          121      20181217
2       C          110      20181217
2       D          105      20181217
1       A          100      20181218
```

Comment: I don't see the point of the `UNION`.  What would be wrong with just removing the `WHERE` check on `Shop` and `Manager` ?

Comment: Im sorry Im new at this and don't quite understand your point.  Every Shop and Manager cleans their own data periodically.  So not everyone has the same date on which the data is last cleaned.  I expect I would have to find out for each manager when the last cleaning date is and merge accordingly

Comment: `UNION` only removes duplicates, it does not remove the final remaining record in a set of duplicates.  So, why wouldn't your query just return the entire table?

Comment: just edited the question with an example.  not sure if it clarifies it more

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it with one shop and one manager, you can do it for all. The thing that is limiting in your sample query is `where Shop = 1 and Manager = 'A'`.

If you get rid of that (everywhere), you only have one more hurdle:  "join"ing cleantable with datatable in the UNION query. How might you do that? Something like `where cleantable.shop = datatable.shop AND cleantable.manager = datatable.manager` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well after the sample data you posted:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM datatable d
  WHERE d.Date > (
      COALESCE((SELECT MAX(Date) FROM cleantable c WHERE c.Shop = d.Shop AND c.Manager = d.Manager), '')
  )  
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM cleantable) 
ORDER BY Date, Shop, Manager;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  But after the data is cleaned, Sales will be potentially different.  So lines are no longer duplicated.  Can I get union to reject duplicate lines only looking at Shop/Manager/Date ?

Comment: @hjw If you mean that you want only Shop/Manager/Date in your results of course you can use UNION, just replace `*` with `Shop, Manager, Date`. If you mean something else then it's better to post some sample data for both tables and the result you expect.

Comment: ty for your time.  I have editted the question again to specify the desired output as well as how the 2 tables look like